# Help in a simple homework exercise

Tags: c#

I need to create a method, in the following signature:

```
int x (int y);
```

That's the example of values that this it should return:

```
x(3) = 1
x(4) = 1
x(5) = 2
x(6) = 2
x(7) = 3
x(8) = 3
x(9) = 4
x(10) = 4
...
```

Any ideas how could I do it?

Thank you.

**EDIT:** That's what I've got so far:

```
    static int x(int y)
    {
        return (y / 2) - 1;
    }
```

but the problem is that:

```
x(3) = 0
x(4) = 1
x(5) = 1
x(6) = 2
```

Comment: what is the mathematical function, this Method should be based ? have you worked over that ?

Comment: your '...' is very important I suspect since the pattern is NOT obvious...at least to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subtract 1 then integer divide by 2.

Comment: Thank you! but I should help in Stack Overflow when there's a test... Can you please tell me how did you find it? Thanks!

Comment: It's a stepped linear progression. "Stepped" means that flooring or integer division is involved, and "linear" means multiplication by a constant. Shifting the progression so that the x-intercept is at the origin gives a translation of -1, and the slope being 1/2 means division by 2.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make a joke of those who asked you to do this (and if you know only values for 3 .. 10), you could also write the following method:

```
static int x(int y) {
  return (int)(10.0 * Math.Sin((double)y / 21.0));
}
```

It's probably not what they meant, but it should give the same results for arguments from 3 to 10 :-). And how did I find it? I know the graph of `sin` function, which is ascending in the beginning. Then I just tried to find out some 'magic constants' to find a configuration in which it returns the numbers you wanted...

Comment: funny, but they ended the sequence with "...", so it looks like he is accepting numbers from 3 to infinity.

Comment: `(int)(10 * Math.Sin(y / 21d))`

Comment: @Yuriy: thanks, fixed. @wallacoloo: Well, the function works for numbers from 3 to infinity. It just gives different results than the most obvious function, but that doesn't mean its wrong (if you know only values [x(3), ..., x(10)] - if you knew more values, you could decide which one is correct, or find other functions...).

Comment: This is probably the intended answer.